# AWS EMR Process using memory after Spark Application compeltes

Tags: amazon-web-services, apache-spark, memory-leaks, out-of-memory

I'm trying to figure out the cause of an Out Of Memory error that I get on an AWS EMR instance.
I've noticed that once the Spark application/step has completed the memory being consumed, showing by htop, is gradually incrementing.  It levels out eventually.
If I then re-run the Spark app/step this behaviour repeats itself until eventually after several iterations I get an Out Of Memory exception due to therenot being enough heap space for the app.

I've tried monitoring this using htop and recorded the memory spikes but it's proving quite difficult to track down the cause.  It would appear as though a process is remaining after the application has run which is then using the memory, but this is just a guess.
I thought that maybe the garbage collection was failing but even this is difficult to trace.  And so i find myself asking if anyone may have experienced the same and how they may have solved the issue.
I'm unable to profile the app on an application level remotely.
Thanks.

Comment: Is this occurring on master node?  What process is using the memory?

Comment: @ChristopherB this is on the master node, I'm running the spark app in client mode.
I'm not sure of the process that was maintaining the memory, I had to kill the EMR as it was on for some time and needed to spin up another one, since then results have been strange, today - the memory is not increasing.  I have no idea why, nothing has changed, they are idential.

Comment: If you share the issue and cluster id at https://forums.aws.amazon.com/forum.jspa?forumID=52 the support teams can review even terminated clusters to help identify root cause.

Comment: @ChristopherB, thank you - I'll do that.  After following the link I see that this si the forum I posted on earlier, added the ids though